.NET MAUI - Map control loading and MoveToRegion method are not working as expected
I am trying to implement the Google Maps map with Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps in a section of a page that is only shown when a button is pressed. I am encountering various problems with moving the centre of the map. I have found that if the map is loaded at the moment the button is pressed, the MoveToRegion(MapSpan) method does not work and the map is loaded with centre at the coordinate point (0, 0). To overcome this problem, I hid this section of the page under another element and only show it at actual size when the button is pressed. However, this is not optimal as calls are made to the Google Maps API even when one should not, resulting in higher costs for using the service. Still, another problem remains. If I try to use the MoveToRegion method after having already set a centre, it does not work and the map does not move.
More details on the project:
It is based on .NET 7.
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps version 7.0.101.
Used MVVM pattern.
The map is implemented on the page with a custom control, in whose code behind it the MoveToRegion is performed when a property linked with the custom control changes.
I have checked that the coordinates passed differ from those currently displayed as the centre, but the map still does not move.
This could be a problem related to the delay in loading the map on the screen, as the MVVM pattern is used. This remains only a hypothesis at the moment.
This is the XAML of the CustomControl:
<maps:Map x:Name="Map"
          IsScrollEnabled="{Binding IsScrollEnabled}"
          IsShowingUser="{Binding IsShowingUser}"
          IsTrafficEnabled="{Binding IsTrafficEnabled}"
          IsZoomEnabled="{Binding IsZoomEnabled}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}">
    <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:MapPinViewModel">
            <maps:Pin Address="{Binding Address}"
                      Label="{Binding Title}"
                      Location="{Binding Location}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
</maps:Map>

This is the code behind of the custom control:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;
using xxx.ViewModels;
using static Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableProperty;

namespace xxx
{
    public partial class MapView : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty AddressLabelProperty = Create(nameof(AddressLabel), typeof(string), typeof(MapView));
        public static readonly BindableProperty CenterProperty = Create(nameof(Center), typeof(Location), typeof(MapView));
        public static readonly BindableProperty DesiredHeightProperty = Create(nameof(DesiredHeight), typeof(double), typeof(MapView), 350D);
        public static readonly BindableProperty GoToAddressListCommandProperty = Create(nameof(GoToAddressListCommand), typeof(IRelayCommand), typeof(MapView));
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsScrollEnabledProperty = Create(nameof(IsScrollEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(MapView), false);
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsShowingUserProperty = Create(nameof(IsShowingUserProperty), typeof(bool), typeof(MapView), false);
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsTrafficEnabledProperty = Create(nameof(IsTrafficEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(MapView), false);
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsZoomEnabledProperty = Create(nameof(IsZoomEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(MapView), false);
        public static readonly BindableProperty PinsProperty = Create(nameof(Pins), typeof(IEnumerable<MapPinViewModel>), typeof(MapView));
        public new static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty = Create(nameof(IsVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(MapView), false, propertyChanged: OnIsVisibleChanged);

        public string AddressLabel
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this.GetValue(AddressLabelProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(AddressLabelProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public Location Center
        {
            get
            {
                return (Location)this.GetValue(CenterProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public double DesiredHeight
        {
            get
            {
                return (double)this.GetValue(DesiredHeightProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(DesiredHeightProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public IRelayCommand GoToAddressListCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return (IRelayCommand)this.GetValue(GoToAddressListCommandProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(GoToAddressListCommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsScrollEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(IsScrollEnabledProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(IsScrollEnabledProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsShowingUser
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(IsShowingUserProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(IsShowingUserProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsTrafficEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(IsTrafficEnabledProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(IsTrafficEnabledProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public new bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public bool IsZoomEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(IsZoomEnabledProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(IsZoomEnabledProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<MapPinViewModel> Pins
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerable<MapPinViewModel>)this.GetValue(PinsProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(PinsProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public MapView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void OnIsVisibleChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            MapView mapView = bindable as MapView;
            if (mapView == null)
                return;

            bool? isVisible = newValue as bool?;
            if (!isVisible.HasValue)
                return;

            if (isVisible.Value)
            {
                mapView.Grid.HeightRequest = mapView.DesiredHeight;

                if (mapView.Center != null)
                {
                    MapSpan mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Location(mapView.Center.Latitude, mapView.Center.Longitude), new Distance(500));

                    mapView.Map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
                }
            }
            else
                mapView.Grid.HeightRequest = 1D;
        }
    }
}


Is there any log about this problem? Could you please share it here?

There are no specific logs for this section. The only thing I can add is that when opening the CustomControl for the first time, 90 lines of  '[Counters] exceeded sample count in FrameTime' appears in the output.
This only happens the first time, at the following times nothing is logged

You can recheck if you have added the actual Maps API key in your app.

Yeah, of course. Otherwise, the map would not be shown

How can we reproduce this problem on our side? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?
